# Homework problem about closed sets and limit points

Tags: general-topology

#### Definition:

$z \in \mathbb{C} $ is called a limit point of $\Omega$ if there exists a sequence of points $z_n \in \Omega$ such that $z_n \neq z $ and $\lim z_n = z $.

#### Homework exercise

Please show carefully that $\Omega$ is closed iff $\{ \text{limit} \; \text{points } \; \text{of} \; \Omega \} \subset \Omega $

#### Try

Suppose $\Omega $ is closed. So by definition $\mathbb{C} \setminus \Omega $ is open. Suppose $z \in \{ \text{limit} \; \text{points } \; \text{of} \; \Omega \}$. We must show $z \in \Omega$. If not, then $z \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \Omega$. By openness, we can find some $r > 0$ such that $D_r (z) \subset \mathbb{C} \setminus \Omega $. Also, we can find a sequence $(z_n) \subset \Omega$ such that $z_n \neq z $ and $z_n \to z $. With $\epsilon = r $, we can find $N$ such that for all $n \geq N $, $|z_n - z| < r $. In particular, for $n = N$, we have that $z_N \in D_r(z) $. But we assumed $z_N \in \Omega$. This contradiction establishes that $z \in \Omega$ as desired.

Conversely, suppose $\{ \text{limit} \; \text{points } \; \text{of} \; \Omega \} \subset \Omega $. We show that $\Omega $ is closed. suppose not, then $\mathbb{C} \setminus \Omega $ is not open. This means that there is some $z \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \Omega $ such that for all $r> 0$ the disc $D_r(z) $ is contained in $\Omega$. Here is where I am stuck since I don't know how to arrive to a contradiction. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Also, Id like some feedback about my proof. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Note that in the second part of your proof it is not correct that $D_r(z)$ is contained in $\Omega$ for all $r > 0$. Instead $D_r(z)$ intersects $\Omega$ nontrivially for all $r > 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $\{ \text{limit} \; \text{points } \; \text{of} \; \Omega \} \subset \Omega $. We show that $\Omega $ is closed.

Suppose not, then $\mathbb{C} \setminus \Omega $ is not open. This means that there is some $z \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \Omega $ such that for all $r> 0$ the ball $B_r(z) $ is **not** contained in $\Omega$, i.e. $B_r(z)\cap \Omega\not=\emptyset$. PIck $z_n\in B_{\frac{1}{n}}(z)\cap \Omega$, for each $n$. Since $z\not\in\Omega,z_n\not=z$. Let $n\to \infty$, we have a convergent sequence $z_n\to z$, hence $z$ is a limit point not in $\Omega$, we get a contradiction.